# Pandas Select Rows Start to End with Specific Starting Value in Column

Tags: pandas, slice, rows, drop

this is something simple but I have not found an answer. I have a dataframe 'df1' that looks like this:

```
    year      5
0   1948 -99.99
1   1949 -99.99
2   1950  -1.74
3   1951   0.17
4   1952  -0.93
```

And, I simply need to select rows beginning with the 'year' column == 1950 and then to the end of the rows (which in this case is '1952').

I have tried this below but I just get "False", "True" but I just get a "True" when 'yearstart' = 1950. So, if 'yearstart' == 1950, i get the following. I'm not sure how to execute a yearstart and extract all the data to the end of the rows.

```
yearstart = 1950

df2 = [df1.year==yearstart]
```

I get this -

```
[0     False
 1     False
 2      True
 3     False
 4     False
```

What I need is this:

```
df2 = 

    year      5
0   1950  -1.74
1   1951   0.17
2   1952  -0.93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `idxmax` and `iloc`:

```
>>> df.iloc[df['year'].eq(1950).idxmax():]
   year     5
2  1950 -1.74
3  1951  0.17
4  1952 -0.93
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the years are sorted or if you want all years greater or equal to 1950, you can use `query`:

```
df.query('year >= 1950')
```

output:

```
   year     5
2  1950 -1.74
3  1951  0.17
4  1952 -0.93
```

Comment: for some reason, i;m getting this error - TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Are the values in year strings of int? If strings, use `df.query('year >= "1950"')`, or better, convert first to int

Comment: ok, how od i convert an entire column to 'int'? yes, they are strings.

Comment: `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)`

Comment: But I'm confused, how did the accepted answer work for you if the values are strings?

Answer (score 0):

df2 = df1[df1['year'] >= 1950]

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.